# CSS box-radius ruins box-shadow inset effect on firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` tag that I want to style with rounded top corners. And, I am facing an issue with my `box-radius`.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 20px 3px 1px #4D7594;
  box-shadow: inset 0 20px 3px 1px #4D7594;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Well, so far works good. But in this sample, if I add more `px` to my `border-radius`, it will break the inset of `box-shadow`.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 20px 3px 1px #4D7594;
  box-shadow: inset 0 20px 3px 1px #4D7594;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

You may notice that on the top area of the `.box` seems to have its shadow missing. This behavior only happens on **firefox**. And currently, I am using **firefox 45.0.1**.

Comment: What happens if you increase the box shadow as well?

Comment: @LGSon If I increase the vertical length of `box-shadow` to `25px`, the `border-radius: 16px` works just fine. But yet, if I increase the `border-radius` to `21px`, it will break again.

Comment: I noticed lately that box-shadow in firefox became very light and very different from other browser,maybe abug  already listed  here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=box-shadow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting two shadows seems to fix it at this time :

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 20px 3px 1px #4D7594;
  box-shadow: inset 0 18px  #4D7594, inset 0 20px 3px 1px #4D7594;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: So, it seems like the issue was not on its vertical length. By setting its blur radius and spread on the second shadow have actually fixed my issue. Though, it looks like a hack to fix this kind of bug. Thanks for noticing it btw..